# strip 0 from all rows in single column MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to `TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM month) FROM table1`

where `table1` has column `month` with data formatted like so: 01, 02, 03

I would like to **update** the data so it is formatted as: 1, 2, 3, ...

Thanks!

Comment: beats me. I've updated the question. I want to update all the rows in the database who's month column has a leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way might be to just cast it to an int:

```
SELECT CAST(month as int) from table
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, though I did it through my PHP script. But what I am really trying to get at is how to update all the existing entries in my database that are formatted with a leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL docs:

```
mysql> SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03');
-> 2
```

So, if you only have the month (and not the rest of the date), you could use:

```
SELECT MONTH(CONCAT('2010-', month, '-', '01')) FROM table1;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month